# Merge data frames based on rownames in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

How can I merge the columns of two data frames, containing a distinct set of columns but *some* rows with the same names? The fields for rows that don't occur in both data frames should be filled with zeros:

```
> d
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i  j
1 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10
2 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9  1
> e
   k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t
1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
3 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
> de
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t
1 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
2 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

See `?merge`:

> the name "row.names" or the number 0 specifies the row names.

Example:

```
R> de <- merge(d, e, by=0, all=TRUE)  # merge by row names (by=0 or by="row.names")
R> de[is.na(de)] <- 0                 # replace NA values
R> de
  Row.names   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s
1         1 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
2         2 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3         3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
   t
1 20
2  0
3 30
```

Comment: That does the job, thanks. Is there any way that is more performant? It takes minutes to do merge two columns with 200k rows, it even takes minutes to merge an empty dataframe with a single-column data frame that has 200k rows...

Comment: and is there any way to preserve the row names? and not get them moved in a dedicated column? of course one can do `rownames(de)=de$Row.names` afterwards, just wondering if there is a way to not break it in the first place...

Comment: what would not breaking it look like?

Comment: @John like `rownames(de)=de$Row.names; de=de[2:length(de)]`

Comment: That's not possible with `merge`. See the help file: "The columns are the common columns followed by the remaining columns in x and then those in y."

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do this with [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) (and tidyverse):

```
library(tidyverse)

full_join(d |> rownames_to_column("id"),
          e |> rownames_to_column("id"), by="id") |> 
          mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(., 0)))
```

Output:

```
  id   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t
1  1 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
2  2 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  3 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Comment: `rownames_to_column` is a function from the `tibble` package. If you want to only use `dplyr` you could use `as_tibble(d, rownames = "id"))`. Note `as_tibble` is imported into `dplyr` from the `tibble` package.

Comment: thank you @LMc (apologies for not replying sooner!). Also I wasn't familiar with this function of as_tibble(), thanks for sharing <3