# How to merge rows of a matrix based on another dataframe that also has those rownames in R?

Tags: r

I have a **matrix** with rownames (e.g. A, B, C).
I also have a **dataframe** with a column named **sampleid** that contains A B and C. Next to this column are individual IDs where some are duplicated (1, 1, 2).

So how would I merge (by average and not sum) the matrix rownames that share the same **Individual ID** in the separate dataframe (df). In this case, rows A and B would be merged (or aggregated if you willAs a reminder df contains the matrix rownames as well in the column **sampleid**. I can convert this column to rownames as well if that is easier so the rownames match. And would appreciate an answer in R but can also use python.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you actually provide a reproducible example of the matrix and the dataframe? It would be a lot easier to help that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `by.y` here and set it equal to zero to [merge by row names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739578/merge-data-frames-based-on-rownames-in-r):

Data

```
# matrix
m <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:2], c("col1", "col2")))

# data frame
d <- data.frame(sampleid = LETTERS[1:5],
                other = runif(5))
```

Code

```
merge(d, m, by.x = "sampleid", by.y = 0)
```

Output

```
#   sampleid     other col1 col2
# 1        A 0.6861468    1    3
# 2        B 0.6296093    2    4
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(data.table)
x <- matrix(1:3, 3, 1, dimnames = list(letters[1:3], "x"))
d <- data.frame(sampleid = c("a", "b", "c"), IndividualID = c(1, 1, 2), y = $
print(x)
  x
a 1
b 2
c 3
print(d)
  sampleid IndividualID  y
1        a            1  8
2        b            1  9
3        c            2 10

d <- as.data.table(d)
x <- cbind(sampleid = rownames(x), as.data.table(x))


out <- merge(x, d, by = "sampleid", all = TRUE)

print(out)
Key: <sampleid>
   sampleid     x IndividualID     y
     <char> <int>        <num> <int>
1:        a     1            1     8
2:        b     2            1     9
3:        c     3            2    10
>
> out[, .(x = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)), by = IndividualID]
   IndividualID     x
          <num> <num>
1:            1   1.5
2:            2   3.0
```